# Eigenvalue, Eigenvector, of a Tridiagonal Symmetric "nearly" Toeplitz Matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, perturbation-theory, symmetric-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

I am trying to find the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of a NxN tridiagonal symmetric "nearly" Toeplitz matrix, except that a modification on the top left corner
\begin{pmatrix}
a^2 & -a \\
-a & 1+a^2 & -a \\
& -a & \ddots & \ddots \\
& & \ddots & \ddots & -a \\
& & & -a & 1+a^2
\end{pmatrix}
and $|a|<1$.
For the case of tridiagonal symmetric Toeplitz matrix, we have analytical expression of both eigenvalues and eigenvectors. With some rank-1 perturbation on the top-left corner, maybe the best we could do is to find numerical solution of eigenvalues/eigenvectors. From numerical experience, 1 out of N eigenvalues will fall out of range, accordingly, the associated eigenvector pair behave unusual (should be sinusoidal functions without perturbation).
I hope someone could shed some light on this problem, is there any to determine this specific least eigenvalue/eigenvector? Or, could we show that this least eigenvalue decays as N gets bigger?
I found some similar problem here: [Eigenvectors of almost-Toeplitz tridiagonal matrix.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186782/eigenvectors-of-almost-toeplitz-tridiagonal-matrix), however, we don't have anything analytical.